Tensorflow model won't train. Help me find the answer
I have this code: https://pastebin.com/ijHx7y2Q .
The code should train a model using mfcc coef to recognize a speaker.
As this is my first project where i play with "AI", i used the dataset (with some additions) and the code from this tutorial: https://www.kaggle.com/code/auishikpyne/speaker-identification . He used to extract features from fft, but as i tried it (also, training my voice, as this this is the condition imposed by my college professor) it's not very accurate... more guessing than predicting.
Confusion matrix is bad, as you can see:
This is the sumary of my model:
As for mfcc, I hope I extracted the coefs good... This is the error that i encounter:
2024-04-16 00:45:46.729545: W tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:404] Local rendezvous is aborting with status: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Incompatible shapes: [1,1,128] vs. [0,16000,16]
         [[{{function_node __inference_one_step_on_data_4280}}{{node functional_1_1/conv1d_15_1/add}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\PSV trainer\TRAINERmfcc.py", line 246, in <module>
    history = model.fit(
              ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 123, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node functional_1_1/conv1d_15_1/add defined at (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\PSV trainer\TRAINERmfcc.py", line 246, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 323, in fit

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 117, in one_step_on_iterator

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 105, in one_step_on_data

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\backend\tensorflow\trainer.py", line 56, in train_step

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 816, in __call__

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 42, in __call__

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 157, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 188, in call

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\function.py", line 153, in _run_through_graph

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 572, in call

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 816, in __call__

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 118, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 42, in __call__

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 157, in error_handler

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\convolutional\conv1d.py", line 164, in call

Incompatible shapes: [1,1,128] vs. [0,16000,16]
         [[{{node functional_1_1/conv1d_15_1/add}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_4385]

Tried using chatGPT, it's not getting it. I asked my teacher, he tried to help me, but because he has limited time and many students to help, he said that I am on my own. I tried to look on tensorflow documentation, reading what would connect with my problem, I didn't understand much... I spent 2 days on this problem, maybe it's a stupid question, but for me it's pretty hardcore. So, thanks in advance! :)
